# SELECT SUM mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I need to select a sum of data for every day where employees belong to a department, I want to be able to select a date range and have a summary of every day is this possible, at the moment i am just getting a summary of the whole date range in one field.

This is my query at the moment

```
select 
  date, 
  SUM(no_of_live_products) 
from 
    fulfilment 
INNER JOIN 
  employee 
  ON  employee.employee_id = fulfilment.employee_id 
where 
      employee.department = 'Telecoms    Services' 
  and date >= '2013-09-16' 
  and date <= '2013-09-29'
```

Is it possible to get a summary of data for every day within that date range or not?

Comment: Seems like you should add a GROUP BY.

Comment: Ordinarily, you cannot return data that does not exist. There are some hacks for fudging this in MySQL but generally it's better to handle application level logic at the 'application level'.

Comment: cheers @X.L.Ant That worked a treat

Comment: @Strawberry I was trying to work out the logic in mysql to be able to then do it at the application level now I've fixed it cheers anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

```
GROUP BY `date`
```

to see the sum per day

Comment: you life saver! I will make your answer the accepted answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of days and you have several time ranges,

First, get the number of dates for a single time range, then sum these up (needs a subselect).

Take this as an example, it's not a complete query for your situation:

```
SELECT SUM(x.days)
FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, startDate, endDate) AS days
    FROM fulfilment 
) x
GROUP BY employee.employee_id
```

Comment: Thats a good query to get the difference in days thank you but not what I was after, may come in handy in the future though

Answer (score 1):

why not try

```
SELECT 
  date, 
  SUM(no_of_live_products) 
FROM 
    fulfilment 
INNER JOIN 
  employee ON  employee.employee_id = fulfilment.employee_id 
WHERE 
      employee.department = 'Telecoms    Services' 
  AND date >= '2013-09-16' 
  AND date <= '2013-09-29'
GROUP BY date(date)
```

Comment: Cheers I have fixed this using the same method but mentioned further up. Much Appreciated